# Delay between requests in Apify

Tags: web-scraping, delay, apify

[Apify's legacy Crawler](https://apify.com/docs/crawler) had a `randomWaitBetweenRequests` option :

> This option forces the crawler to ensure a minimum time interval between opening two web pages, in order to prevent it from overloading the target server.

Do Apify Actors have a similar setting ?  If so, how does it impact the Actor Units computation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no options like that in [apify/web-scraper](https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper), which should replace legacy crawler option.

But there is a way how to implement this yourself in pageFunction. You can simply use context.waitFor() function and pass there random time in ms.

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { request, log, jQuery } = context;

    // To be able to use jQuery as $, one needs save it into a variable
    // and select the inject jQuery option. We've selected it for you.
    const $ = jQuery;
    const title = $('title').text();

    log.info(`URL: ${request.url} TITLE: ${title}`);

    // This waits time in ms, which getRandomWait returns.
    await context.waitFor(getRandomWait());

    // To save data just return an object with the requested properties.
    return {
        url: request.url,
        title
    };
}
```

If you want to have this option in apify/web-scraper, you can submit an issue on [GitHub repo](https://github.com/apifytech/actor-scraper/issues).

Comment: Note that if `waitFor` does not exist on context object (it does not for me, maybe because I'm using newer version, maybe because I'm using BasicCrawler), plain `await Apify.utils.sleep(_.random(500, 3000))` in `handleRequestFunction`/`handlePageFunction` works too